# How to make a page title linkable/clickable?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, page-layout

I want to make my **Page Title** linkable/clickable so that users can be able click for their home page. Is it possible to include this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this below script in CEWP on your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea span span a").attr("href", _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    });
</script>
```

It will redirect to your home page.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by keeping the following code in Content Editor WebPart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').wrap('<a href="Your Link" />');

});
```

Where `DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea` is the Id of your title placeholder.

I achieved this functionality in past.

Comment: have tried yours but for some reason does'nt go to the home page

Comment: if will work if your URL is correct. I tried and then posted the answer.